# Словарь частот C++

Tags: c++, c++11, map, compare

**Задача:** Напишите программу, которая строит алфавитно-частотный словарь для файла input.txt , в котором в столбик записаны слова, состоящие только из строчных букв латинского алфавита. Слова нужно отсортировать в порядке убывания частоты (сначала слова, которые встретились чаще всего). Слова с одинаковой частотой должны располагаться в алфавитном порядке.

Входные данные
Входной файл содержит неизвестное количество строк, в каждой из которых записано слово, состоящее только из строчных букв латинского алфавита. Последняя строка файла – пустая.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести в файл output.txt все различные слова, которые встретились исходном файле, по одному слову в строке. После каждого слова через пробел записывается количество таких слов в файле. Слова должны быть отсортированы по убыванию частоты (сначала слова, которые встретились чаще всего). Слова с одинаковой частотой должны располагаться в алфавитном порядке.

Примеры
входные данные
i
was
he
was
she
he
выходные данные
he 2
was 2
i 1
she 1

Я написал сохранение слов в словарь, подсчёт кол-ва повторений, вектор с ключами. Далее попытался написать сортировку с компаратором, но святой *Информатикс* выдаёт ошибку на четвёртом тесте.
[Ссылка на задачу](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=11546&chapterid=112511#1)

код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> dict;

bool comp(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    if(dict[a] == dict[b] and a < b){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    string s;

    vector<string> keys;
    while (cin >> s){
        if(!dict.count(s)){
            dict[s] = 1;
            keys.push_back(s);
        }
        else{
            dict[s]++;
        }
    }
    sort(keys.begin(), keys.end(), [](const string& a, const string& b){ return dict[a] > dict[b];});
    sort(keys.begin(), keys.end(), comp);
    for(auto i: keys){
        cout << i << " " << dict[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"выдаёт ошибку"* Какую ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то вы странно дважды сортируете один вектор... Вторая сортировка ведь убивает результаты первой. Тогда хотя бы `stable_sort` надо использовать.

Но можно проще. Собрать статистику, занести в файл *пар*, и отсортировать один раз, не дергая `dict`. Использование `map` оставим для упрощения набора статистики...

```
int main()
{

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    map<string, int> dict;
    string s;
    while (cin >> s) dict[s]++;

    vector<pair<string,int>> v;
    for(const auto& x: dict) v.push_back(x);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
         [](const auto&a, const auto&b)
         {
             if (a.second > b.second) return true;
             else if (a.second < b.second) return false;
             else return a.first < b.first;
         }
         );

    for(auto x: v){
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    }
}
```